# GetPivotData Number Fomatted as Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I am using JobNumber in a couple of different pivot tables to pull out data. JobNumber is a numeric number, but Excel sometimes stores it as a number formatted as text.  Sometimes I find the data using the number and sometimes I find the data using the text.

Using number:
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("ODC Cost",'ODC Pivot'!$A$1, "Job No.", 74010000002),0)

Using text:
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("ODC Cost",'ODC Pivot'!$A$1, "Job No.", "74010000002"),0)

I would like to be able to find all instances of 74010000002 no matter whether it is a number or text.

Answer (score 0):

The VALUE() function converts text to a number.  Would wrapping all the numbers / texts inside the VALUE() function work?